# Gravity slowing down

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am currently developing an application in Xcode and am trying to slow down the gravity that effects an item which drops from the top of the screen to the bottom.

```
item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Coin");
        item!.name = "Coin";
        item!.setScale(1.2);
        item!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: item!.size.height / 2);
        item!.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

so far that is what i got but the gravity is still a bit too fast. Is there anyway to tone it down even more?

Comment: You do not want to change the gravity, unless you want all items to be affected by the same gravity.  You want to look into `linearDamping` to slow down your object (Basically add air resistance)

Comment: so each object has its own linearDamping. Thank you ill give it a go